# 数日間の質問制限を受けた時のページにモバイル版がほしい

Tags: 機能の要求, モバイル

昨日既に２回質問した状況です。Androidからうっかり「質問する」を押してしまった所、次のようなPC版のページに飛ばされてしまいました。

> You have reached your question limit
>   It looks like you might need a break - take a breather and come back soon!
>   ...

このページのモバイル対応版を用意していただけないでしょうか。